# Can I install 64-bit OS on my Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit, dell-inspiron

My Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop features the Intel Pentium Dual Core T4200 processor. When I bought it, it came preinstalled with Windows Vista Home Basic, 32-bit. I'm considering upgrading it to Windows 7 Home Premium, but I don't know whether I should order the 64-bit or 32-bit version. The information I found on the web has been confusing.

Does anyone know if my laptop supports 64-bit OS?

Comment: Yes.
http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=37251

Answer (score 2):

Go to support.dell.com and enter your laptop service tag. Look at the shipped configuration, locate the row for the CPU. Is it a 5000 series? If so, it is a 64 bit.

Or, a less scientific method would be to look at the drivers list and see if there are any 64 bit drivers.

(My Dell laptop has a 64 bit CPU but only preinstalled Vista Home 32 bit :-(  )

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a program like [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php) to see your processor information

You'll want to look for either `EM64T` or `AMD64` in the "Instructions" field:

[image: CPU-Z Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Before spending the money for a 64 bit OS, you may wish to make sure that the rest of the chipset can take advantage of the extra address space. I was very disappointed to find out that, even with a 64 bit OS on a Dell D820, I could still only access a maximum of 3.2 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

The **[Pentium 4 Dual Core T4200](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=37251)** has a 64-bit instruction set alright, but this is not the only criterion. I recommend to use the **[Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1B544E90-7659-4BD9-9E51-2497C146AF15&displaylang=en)**.

The program will tell you if your system is suitable for 64-bit Windows.

[image]

Comment: @Molly - is that your machine?

Comment: nope, just a screenshot found at GIS

Answer (score 0):

According to Intel sSpec finder, your Pentium Dual Core T4200 does indeed have 64-bit support.

http://processorfinder.intel.com/details.aspx?sSpec=SLGJN

Just make sure the rest of your machines meets the requirements for Windows 7.  Otherwise you could rock Vista or XP x64 -- but I don't see why your machine wouldn't run Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0):

***strong text***
if your system is sport 32 bit of windows OS u can by or upgrade 32 bit OS coz your system is build with  32 bit sporting hard wears